# Azure Functions breaking on request loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-async

I have Node.js function that runs fine locally, however in an Azure Serverless Function (HTTP Trigger), it unexpectedly stops on a request loop if one of the requests responds with an empty request.body, instead of continuing to through the rest of the loop.

Below is an example of the code and then console.log's to show where the function is being stopped.

```
    const ids = [1, 2]
    const responses = ids.map(async ids => {
     const response = await axios.get(
       `${URL}/api/purchase/${ids}/details`,
       headers
      );
     console.log("Status: ", response.status);
     console.log("Response: ", response.data);
     return response.data;
    });
   const responseCollection = await Promise.all(responses);
```

Below is the log:

```
 [Information] Status 200
 [Information] Response []
 [Information] Executed 'Functions.my-func' (Succeeded, Id=21988***)
 [Information] Status 200
 [Information] Response [data:{number:2}]
```

As you can see in the log, as soon as it gets an empty response body, it breaks without continuing. This is shown with the 'Executed' flag.

On a local Node.js application with the same code, it continues the loop and the Promise.all fires after to combine both the empty response with the other non empty one.
Is there anyway to avoid it stopping on an Azure Serverless Function?

Comment: You are _definitely_ sure its breaking the loop or is the log just coming out in the wrong order?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I've tried with more data and can see the same result after the first request. Also, I have an Try/Catch block around this and the Catch (error) it getting called.

Comment: Ah ok, if it's throwing an error then of course it's going to exit early as you `await` the promise list :) (you didn't mention that in your question). So what does the API respond with when it can't find a purchase?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Well, it does have a response, eg, response.status = 200 etc, just the response.body is an empty array. The strange thing is, I have the same version of Node locally (10.15.2), and the exact same code runs without going to the catch.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to stab a guess at the issue being related to the format of the response not being valid (if it's JSON `[]` should be valid though) but it would be easier if you logged out the error via `try...catch`, inside your map function. In fact, it may make sense to do that in general as to avoid stopping the rest of the requests if one particular request does fail.